# What's the difference between (1,) and (1) in Python

Tags: python, tuples, element

As stated in the title, I found that `(1)` and `(1,)` are different. But what's the difference of them?

```py
In[39]: (1) == (1,)
Out[39]: False
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The comma makes it a tuple.  (1) is just the same as 1 wrapped in delimiters.

Answer (score 17):

Try this to convince yourself:

```
>>> type((1))
<type 'int'>
>>> type((1,))
<type 'tuple'>
```

The following identity checks may provide you with further insight into the differences:

```
>>> (1) is 1
True
>>> (1,) is 1
False
```