# What's the meaning of "(1,) == 1," in Python?

Tags: python, tuples, equals-operator

I'm testing the tuple structure, and I found it's strange when I use the `==` operator like:

```
>>>  (1,) == 1,
Out: (False,)
```

When I assign these two expressions to a variable, the result is true:

```
>>> a = (1,)
>>> b = 1,
>>> a==b
Out: True
```

This questions is different from [Python tuple trailing comma syntax rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992559/python-tuple-trailing-comma-syntax-rule) in my view. I ask the group of expressions between `==` operator.

Comment: Looking at a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312512/whats-the-difference-between-1-and-1-in-python) by the OP just 2 hours ago, It seems wonderful (or strange) that how just framing of a question differently can lead to different results (and acceptance among the community).

Comment: @AKS These are different qestions

Comment: @AKS While the questions are marginally different here, I agree completely with your point. Herd effect aka HNQ.

Comment: @AKS These questions are different. The second is about expressions group and first is about tulle. I think it is acceptable to have two questions from same topic.

Comment: @PythonNewHand Indeed, it is completely acceptable. That's why I added that _framing a question differently_.

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功 how do you figure? I skimmed those answers and saw nothing that seemed to cover this particular situation.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Other answers have already shown you that the behaviour is due to operator precedence, as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

I'm going to show you how to find the answer yourself next time you have a question similar to this.  You can deconstruct how the expression parses using the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module:

```
>>> import ast
>>> source_code = '(1,) == 1,'
>>> print(ast.dump(ast.parse(source_code), annotate_fields=False))
Module([Expr(Tuple([Compare(Tuple([Num(1)], Load()), [Eq()], [Num(1)])], Load()))])
```

From this we can see that the code gets parsed [as Tim Peters explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37313506/674039):

```
Module([Expr(
    Tuple([
        Compare(
            Tuple([Num(1)], Load()), 
            [Eq()], 
            [Num(1)]
        )
    ], Load())
)])
```

Comment: Another useful tool is `dis` -- In this case, you'd see two `LOAD_CONST` with different values (`(1,)` and `1`) and a `BUILD_TUPLE` opp-code.

Answer (score 157):

This is just operator precedence.  Your first

```
(1,) == 1,
```

groups like so:

```
((1,) == 1),
```

so builds a tuple with a single element from the result of comparing the one-element tuple `1,` to the integer `1` for equality  They're not equal, so you get the 1-tuple `False,` for a result.

Comment: Not really, but 1-tuples have odd syntax.  In general, you'd be far more surprised if, e.g., `1+2, 2==3, 4*7` did _not_ group as `(1+2), (2==3), (4*7)`.  In practice, 1-tuples are hardly ever used (well, outside of StackOverflow questions ;-) ).

Comment: Perhaps "unexpected" would have been a better word to use than "strange." I feel a bit like I'm looking at [one of those drawings that can be two things, depending on your perspective and focus](http://www.today.com/pets/rabbit-or-duck-124-year-old-drawing-has-both-if-t73606). The equality operator is so large compared to the commas, it's easy to focus on it and assume the result will be `True`/`False`. Now that I understand what's happening, it's perfectly obvious and reasonable.

Comment: And now you know what the "Zen of Python" means by saying that the one obvious way to do it "may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch" ;-)

Comment: It's a little bit confusing when you read the doc and see that what makes a tuple is the comma, not the parentheses! So in this statement the comma in the right hand is not considered as a part of the test but it's considered as a separator! Unexpected behavior!

Comment: @TimPeters: "In practice, 1-tuples are hardly ever used" I use them all the time ☺. To extract the item from a list that *should* have only one element. `(e,) = a_list`. That code will crash, as desired, if the list hasn't exactly one element. It's a very lazy way to asser that `len(a_list) == 1`

Comment: @skrrgwasme I would argue that PHP's left-associative ternaries are even stranger. `a?b:c?d:e` is interpreted as `(a?b:c)?d:e`.

Comment: Common advice about expressions is "when in doubt, use parentheses". Following that, it's good to put parentheses around all one-tuples, even though they are not part of the tuple syntax.

Answer (score 13):

When you do

```
>>> (1,) == 1,
```

it builds a tuple with the result from comparing the *tuple* `(1,)` with an *integer* and thus returning `False`.

Instead when you assign to variables, the two *equal tuples* are compared with each other.

You can try:

```
>>> x = 1,
>>> x
(1,)
```