# access a list with indices that are list

Tags: python

I have been assigned an exercise for my python course. The goal is to create some geometric object as subclasses of a Shape object that are going to pass some assertion evaluation.

Here is the code:

```
class Shape(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    def __init__(self, coords):
        super(Shape, self).__init__()
        self._coords = list(map(int, coords))

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._coords[key]

    def move(self, distance):
        self._coords = distance

class Point(Shape):
    def __init__(self, coords):
        super(Point,self).__init__(coords)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Point((0,0))
    p.move((1,1))
    assert p[0,0], p[0,1] == (1,1) # Check the coordinates
```

The question is how can I access a list of coords that is created in Shape super class with list indices?
Is there any possibility for a list to be indexed using another list?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but `p[0,0], p[0,1] == (1,1)` evaluates as `p[0,0], (p[0,1] == (1,1))`

Comment: It is possible to have this:  a = [1,1]
    assert a[0], a[1] == (1,1)

Comment: `a[0], a[1] == (1,1)` will evaluate as `(1, False)`. You probably want `assert (a[0], a[1] == (1,1))`. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37313471/1639625

Comment: You are right! I didn't print the answer to see what I got

Comment: What would `p[1, 0]` or the like be? It doesn't seem obvious and I'm curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact syntax `obj[m,n]==v` is possible if `obj` is a `dict`!

Any [hashable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html) (most immutable) type(s) can be used as a dictionary key. Tuples, such as `(1,2)`, are hashable. It is therefore valid to instantiate a dictionary:

```
>>> my_dict = { (1,2):'A', (6,7,8):'B' }
```

Which can be indexed:

```
>>> my_dict[1,2]
'A'
>>> my_dict[6,7,8]
'B'
>>> assert my_dict[6,7,8] == 'B'
```

This approach would allow you to match the assertion syntax.

Comment: Thank's. I will try to turn my list into a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to access an element from a list inside another list.

For that, you simply write each index in a separate pair of square brackets.

If your list is `nested_list = [ [1, 2] , [3, 4] ]` you access the item `4` like this:

```
print(nested_list[1][0])
```

That is equal to the long form below, which should clarify how chaining the index look-ups works:

```
inner_list = nested_list[1]
print(inner_list[0])
```

Comment: it is easy for me to assert my Point instance with: p[0], p[1] == (1,1). It is True. But I have to explicitly follow the rules of the exercise. The thing is that the pair of coordinates is a list like this p._coords = [1,1]. So I don't know how to implement p[0,0] so as to have access to what it could be easily be accessed as p[0]