# What does (1,) mean in Python?

Tags: python, tuples

I looked at similar questions but I didn't find this topic anywhere.

I want to know what does the tuple `(1,)` mean in Python?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here... it's just a tuple with one element, the integer `1`.

Comment: @ajcr MAN! You have the answer???

Comment: Related, but not really duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37313471/1639625

Comment: @tobias_k Actually that was the question that forced me to ask this.

Comment: That thread would have answered this question sufficiently.

Comment: @vikingben Even tho it's not doc.

Comment: @tobias_k thx 4 link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax

> One Element Tuples
>
> One-element tuples look like:
>
> ```
> 1,
> ```
>
> The essential element here is the trailing comma. As for any
>   expression, parentheses are optional, so you may also write
>   one-element tuples like
>
> ```
> (1,)
> ```
>
> but it is the comma, not the parentheses, that define the tuple.

Comment: Well, [Multiple Element Tuples](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax#Multiple_Element_Tuples) says the comma is also needed there, even though `1, 2, 3` successfully coerces to `(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: No the page clearly says that for multiple element tuples the trailing comma is optional.

Comment: *but the trailing comma is completely optional.* and *but again, it is the commas, not the parentheses, that define the tuple.* seem contradictory to me, tho.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος The page says that for multiple element tuples `The essential elements are the commas **between** each element of the tuple`, so that should answer your question. The only place where trailing comma is essential is the single element case.